# how to use UseScroll on Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vueuse

I am using @vueuse 's useScroll on my nuxt 3 projects.
but useScroll seems not working .
here is the  [codesandbox minimal reprodaction](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Seyid-cmd/nuxt-useScroll/draft/romantic-mendeleev?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl98l35k700hblrgf8mrs6ed6%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl98l3qbs008f3n6h7zz7himb%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl98l3pdi006e3n6h94p39o91%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D).

// app.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { x:mouseX, y:mouseY } = useMouse()

const el = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const { x, y, isScrolling, arrivedState, directions } = useScroll(el)
</script>

<template>

<div>Mouse pos: {{mouseX}}, {{mouseY}}</div>
<div ref="el"></div>


      <NuxtWelcome /> //inserted to make the page long  so we can scroll
      <div>Scroll po pos: {{x}}, {{y}}</div> // here is the problem both x and y are 0,0 no matter how you scroll

  <NuxtWelcome /> //inserted to make the page long so we can scroll

</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the referenced element needs to be scrollable  when overflow in my case style  `overflow:scroll`